# Regex match month name day, year

Tags: python, regex

Trying to extract the date out of this string:

```
Publisher: Broadway Books; Anniversary, Reprint edition (October 8, 2002)
```

I want to get this: `October 8, 2002`

This is the regex I was using. Goal is to make it work for any date in the format above. It works when I test it on https://regex101.com/ but returns "None" in my code.

```
pattern = re.compile("(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}")
date = pattern.match(tag.get_text())
```

Comment: "Does not work" isn't very informative.  Do you get anything? If so, what?  Are you sure `tag` has text that should match? Please provide the value of `tag` so we can try it.

Comment: You should not, in general, use `match`. It is not doing what you think it is doing. Use `search` instead. Your fixed code works for me: `pattern.search("foo October 8, 2002 bar").group(0)` -> `'October 8, 2002'`.

Comment: @cco returns none in the code. I've edited my question above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using `re.match`, which sees if the text matches the pattern at the beginning of the string. Use `re.search` instead, which looks for matches anywhere in the string. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) for more info.

#### Code:

```
import re

text = "Publisher: Broadway Books; Anniversary, Reprint edition (October 8, 2002)"
pattern = re.compile(
    "(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|"
    "Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|"
    "Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}")

print(pattern.match(text))  # prints None
print(pattern.search(text))
print(pattern.search(text).group())
```

#### Results:

```
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(57, 72), match='October 8, 2002'>
October 8, 2002
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. I understand the difference now